# Superposition of energy levels

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy-conservation, atomic-physics, superposition, quantum-measurements

When thinking about a "random" atom in space (say a Hydrogen atom), should I assume that the electron is in a ground state (or any particular excited eigenstate) or is it in a superposition of all energy levels before I measure the energy of the atom?

On the one hand, If the latter is the case that would mean that there is a nonzero probability to measure any arbitrarily large energy for the system, which seems weird. On the other hand, should not any quantum system be assumed to be in a superposition of all the eigenstates before making a measurement, then is there any mechanism by which the superposition of such atom is collapsed even before measurement?

Comment: When you say "a superposition of all energy levels" you are probably right. But by what means do you *weight* the energy levels with some probability? If you get the weights wrong, you end up with an infinite energy.

Comment: That atom in space is interacting with the cosmic microwave background and thus in a 2.7K heat bath. The nonzero temperature means a nonzero probability of being in various excited states.

Comment: Energy (of bound electron in H atom) is typically ~$Z^2e^2/n^2$, so it cannot be arbitrarily large; it goes to zero as $n\to\infty$. Maybe you can consider square well potential where $E_n$~$n^2$

Comment: Only the probability of the variables entering the problem can be known at the quantum mechanical level. see https://physicsworld.com/a/quantum-microscope-peers-into-the-hydrogen-atom/

Comment: buzz word: decoherence.